# Add an appointment in Exchange Server by using Exchange Web Services Api 2.0 and Java

Tags: java, web-services, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2013

I want to add a new appointment in my Exchange server 2013 by using Java and Exchange Web Services Api 2.0.

But I always have this exception :

> Exception in thread "main"
>   microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ServiceRequestException:  The
>   request failed. The request failed. hostname in certificate didn't
>   match: <10.0.6.4> != ms-ex

Here is a part of My code :

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService();
ExchangeCredentials credentials = new WebCredentials("userName", "password");
service.setCredentials(credentials);

service.setUrl(new URI("https:// server address/ews/exchange.asmx"));

Appointment appointment = new Appointment(service);
appointment.setSubject("Appointment subject");
.
.
.
appointment.save();
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an SSL problem. You are accessing the server with a URL that doesn't match the hostnames configured in the SSL cert, so the API gives that error. It's the same as if you browse to that URL, you would get a warning asking if you wish to proceed due to the cert name mismatch. Try using the URL that matches the certificate.